# Python3 block subprocess execution during exception

Tags: python, exception, subprocess

How to block and stop the total script execution if a subprocess.run fails with an exception?

For example, I have a function in which I run a command via subprocess.run, if that command returns an exception I do not want the next subprocess.run to get executed and would like to stop the script execution and exit totally

Comment: Use `except` and `break`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `check=True` keyword argument already does exactly that; it raises an exception if the subprocess did not return a success (zero) exit code.

```py
import subprocess
import logging
import sys

commands = ('true', ['sh', '-c', 'true'], 'false', ['echo', 'hello'])
for cmd in commands:
    try:
        subprocess.run(cmd, check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        logging.error('%r failed', cmd)
        sys.exit(1)
```